# Solving an integral using assumptions

Tags: calculus-and-analysis, assumptions

I am trying to solve the integral

```
Integrate[(Sin(theta))/sqrt((r^2) + (s^2) - 2 rs(cos(theta))), {theta, 0, pi}]
```

with assumptions that `2/s` if `r < s` and `2/r` if `r > s`. However, I'm not sure how to give these assumptions. I also need to make the assumption that `r`and `s` are greater than zero.

The solution to this integral is piecewise.

Comment: Maybe this you want:`{Integrate[
  Sin[theta]/Sqrt[r^2 + s^2 - 2*r*s*Cos[theta]], {theta, 0, Pi}, 
  Assumptions -> {r > 0, s > 0, r < s}], 
 Integrate[
  Sin[theta]/Sqrt[r^2 + s^2 - 2*r*s*Cos[theta]], {theta, 0, Pi}, 
  Assumptions -> {r > 0, s > 0, r > s}]}` ?

Comment: All built-in functions and constants must start with a capital letter (e.g., `Sin`, `Cos`, `Sqrt`, `Pi`). Use brackets `[ ]` to enclose function arguments rather than parentheses. `rs` is not the same as `r*s` or `r s`. For assumptions, what is supposed to be either `2/s` or `2/r` depending on relation between `r` and `s`? Either use `Assumptions` option in `Integrate` or use `Assuming` construct around `Integrate`.

Comment: `Assuming[r > 0 && s > 0 && r != s,
 Integrate[
   Sin[theta]/Sqrt[r^2 + s^2 - 2 r*s*Cos[theta]], {theta, 0, Pi}] // 
  Simplify]`